# Offset destination row downward with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA code to copy some data to another sheet.

```
Sheets("Current").Range("A3:D").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Archive").Cells(1).End(xlDown)
```

When pasting, the code appends the data to the first empty row after all the existing entries. I'd like to offset the paste destination down one row further, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sheets("Current").Range("A3:D").Copy _
    Destination:=Sheets("Archive").Cells(1).End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
```

More robust:

```
Sheets("Current").Range("A3:D").Copy _
    Destination:=Sheets("Archive").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0)
```

Comment: I tried the code, and now it doesn't move it to the bottom of the existing data anymore, instead it copies it into the first row. I reverted the changes, restarted Excel, and it still doesn't work. Any ideas why this might be the case?

Comment: If you went back to your original code and it still doesn't work then I have no idea why: you only posted a single line of code so there's not much to go on there.

Comment: Try the second version above.

Comment: It works, thanks! I have an additional question, what exactly is the effect of changing xlDown to xlUp? Does the first one go from the first to the last row, and the second one go from the last row to the first row?

Comment: Yes, it's just as it appears. `End(xlUp)` has the same effect as selecting a cell then clicking `Ctrl+UpArrow`  and   `xlDown` is similar but in the other direction

Comment: And is the fact that Rows.Count is a default variable what makes it more robust than the first option?

Comment: Not really - going up is typically better because it's less susceptible to problems if (for example) there's no data existing on your sheet (or only one row of data) where using `xlDown` will take you to the bottom if the sheet.